# Hypersphere packings from hypercubic graphs?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Consider a $D$-dimensional hypercubic lattice, i.e. a graph $H$ embedded in ${\mathbb R}^D$ where the vertices have integer coordinates $ (x_1,...,x_D) \in {\mathbb Z}^D$ and edges are between all pairs $ \{ (x_1,...,x_i,...,x_D), (x_1,...,x_i+1,...,x_D)\}$.

From this graph $H$, build a second graph $S$ the following way.

- consider the family of vertices of $H$, embedded in the $D-1$-dimensional hyperplanes $S_t$ defined by $\sum_{i=1}^D x_i = t$ with $t \in {\mathbb Z}$
- consider that there is an edge between two vertices in $S_t$ if, in $H$,  those two vertices have a common neighbour in $S_{t+1}$ or/and $S_{t-1}$.

Obviously $S = \cup_t S_t$ is a disconnected graph with each $S_t$ being a $D-1$ dimensional layer.

I remarked that for $D = 2, 3$, and apparently also for $D=4$, the $S_t$ are actually $D-1$-hypersphere packing contact graphs.

My question is, for what values of $D$ does this hold?

Comment: In your definition of adjacency, do you mean $x_i+1$?

Comment: Right - I've just done the editing.

Comment: If I'm mentally translating right, these entities are usually known as the _$A_n$ lattices_ and you might be able to find useful information on them under that name; in particular, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#An is a decent starting point.  Your intuition is good; they're related to sphere packing, although for $n\gt 3$ they're not the most efficient packings.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll have to dig into root systems then. Yet I would have expected this to hold for a bit more dimensions since up to $D=8$, the compact hypersphere packs are laminated. Or maybe I have to go into the details to see how my $D$ and your $n$ map.

Comment: @Mathias I may be slightly off my mark; this isn't my area of expertise, but I believe what you've described is the $A_n$ lattice as opposed to $D_n$ (my $n$ is your $D-1$); if I'm right, then through up to three dimensions of packing - or 4 dimensions of hypercube - you're correct in your assumption, but then I believe it will break down one dimension higher and no longer be the densest packing.  If you want more reading on this, I highly, highly recommend Conway and Sloane's _Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups_, which is absolutely the canonical reference.

Comment: @Steven - Thanks for your supporting comments. It is a bit disappointing that the story ends with $D=4$, but it actually could be enough for my needs - I'm just a physicist after all!

Comment: Well, keep in mind that it yields a _packing_ in all dimensions; it's just the global optimality that goes away as the dimension increases.  And while it's disappointing, the resulting theory is so rich and fascinating that it's hard (for me) to find it too frustrating.  After all, if the story of packing density ended with $A_n$, we wouldn't have the Leech lattice...